# Reciprocate with negative connotations

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the negative of reciprocate? I need a word which means reciprocate but has negative connotations.

I searched its antonyms but they didn't help me.
[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/reciprocate) says requite, repay and recompense but they don't convey the meaning I want them to convey.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to use *retaliate*.

*[Retaliating](http://www.dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/retaliate)* means *when someone does something bad to you and you in turn do the same to them*.

Example: When someone downvotes your post and you in turn downvote their post, that's called *retaliating*.

> If you retaliate when someone harms or annoys you, you do something which harms or annoys them in return. [**Collins Dictionary**]